LlamaIndex Pandas Query Engine not returning all rows
I am using LlamaIndex Pandas Query Engine to produce a pandas query that is applied on a dataframe. The query produced is correct however the dataframe returned is not. Specifically, a dataframe with 10 rows is returned. These are the first 5 and last 5 rows of the correct dataframe.
When looking at the logs, the correct filter is applied and the resulting dataframe is printed. Because the resulting dataframe is >10 rows it prints the first 5 rows and last 5 rows. It seems like this printed df is what is taken and passed back as a result.
How can I get the full filtered dataframe back? This is what my query pipeline looks like:
    def setup_pipeline(self):
        pandas_prompt = self.create_pandas_prompt(self.df)
        pandas_output_parser = PandasInstructionParser(self.df)

        output_parser = PydanticOutputParser(RetrievalResponse)
        response_prompt_tmpl = self.create_response_synthesis_str()
        json_response_prompt_str = output_parser.format(response_prompt_tmpl)
        response_prompt_tmpl = PromptTemplate(json_response_prompt_str)

        qp = QP(
            modules={
            "input": InputComponent(),
            "pandas_prompt": pandas_prompt,
            "llm1": self.llm,
            "pandas_output_parser": pandas_output_parser,
            "response_synthesis_prompt": response_prompt_tmpl,
            "llm2": self.llm,
            "output_parser": output_parser,
            },
            verbose=True,
        )

        qp.add_chain(["input", "pandas_prompt", "llm1", "pandas_output_parser"])
        qp.add_links(
            [
            Link("input", "response_synthesis_prompt", dest_key="query_str"),
            Link("llm1", "response_synthesis_prompt", dest_key="pandas_instructions"),
            Link(
                "pandas_output_parser",
                "response_synthesis_prompt",
                dest_key="pandas_output",
            ),
            ]
        )
        qp.add_link("response_synthesis_prompt", "llm2")
        qp.add_link("llm2", "output_parser")
        return qp

    def create_pandas_prompt(self, df):
        df_str = df.to_string()
        instruction_str = (
            "1. Convert the query to executable Python code using Pandas.\n"
            "2. The final line of code should be a Python expression that can be called with the `eval()` function.\n"
            "3. The code should represent a solution to the query.\n"
            "4. PRINT ONLY THE EXPRESSION.\n"
            "5. Do not quote the expression.\n"
        )

        pandas_prompt_str = (
            "You are working with a pandas dataframe in Python.\n"
            "The name of the dataframe is `df`.\n"
            "This is the result of `print(df.head())`:\n"
            "{df_str}\n\n"
            "Follow these instructions:\n"
            "{instruction_str}\n"
            "Query: {query_str}\n\n"
            "Expression:"
        )
        return PromptTemplate(pandas_prompt_str).partial_format(
            instruction_str=instruction_str, df_str=df_str
        )

